# Rude/abusive flags

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Глянул [историю своих тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/199934?group=3):

[image: История моих тревог]

Предлагаю заменить `rude/abusive flags` чем-то вроде `тревоги на невежливых/оскорбительных сообщениях`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Почему–то слетел перевод. [Поправил](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/94712515?key=394cb18c988f88818a98aaa407e07bb7)!